# Ajax call to update fields on the HTML page, populate the dropdown-menu, table, and piechart

Tags: javascript, jquery

The purpose of this file is to make an Ajax call to a certain endpoint, and update a certain fields on the HTML page, auto populate the dropdown-menu, table, and piechart.

My script will turn this:

[image]

## to this:

[image]

I'm not sure whether or not I should do all my logic within my Ajax success. Should I separate it? This is what I have. Is it really that bad?

```
'use strict';

define(['jquery', 'moment'], function($, moment) {

    $(function() {

        var report_type_car   = $('#as-report-type-car');
        var report_type_cdr   = $('#as-report-type-cdr');
        var report_type_title = $('#as-report-type-title');
        var section_num       = $('#as-section-num');
        var problem_set       = $('#as-problem-set');
        var start_time        = $('#as-start-time');
        var due_time          = $('#as-due-time');
        var student_am        = $('#as-student-am');
        var student_total     = $('#as-student-total');
        var submit_am         = $('#as-submit-am');
        var submit_total      = $('#as-submit-total');
        var avg_score         = $('#as-avgscore');
        var danger            = $('#pc-danger');
        var warning           = $('#pc-warning');
        var success           = $('#pc-success');
        var danger_list       = $('#pc-danger-list');
        var warning_list      = $('#pc-warning-list');
        var success_list      = $('#pc-success-list');

        //var basePath = "/BIM/resources/js/reports/teacher/section-exercise/assignment/";

        $.ajax({

            url: "/BIM/rest/report/assignment",
            type: "POST",
            dataType: "json",
            data: {
                assessmentId: "206a9246-ce83-412b-b8ad-6b3e28be44e3",
                classroomId: "722bfadb-9774-4d59-9a47-89ac9a7a8f9a"
            },

            success: function(objects) {

                var x = 0;

                function updateInfo(x) {

                    var json = objects.assignments[x].header;
                    var name = objects.assignments[x].name;

                    // Check for space in report_type
                    if (json.report_type.indexOf(' ') >= 0) {

                        var report_type_full = json.report_type.split(/(\s+)/);
                        var car = report_type_full[0];
                        var cdr = report_type_full[2];

                        report_type_car.html(car);
                        report_type_cdr.html(cdr);
                        report_type_title.html(car + " " + cdr + " " + json.section_num);

                    } else {

                        var car = json.report_type;
                        report_type_car.html(car);
                        report_type_title.html(car + " " + json.section_num);
                    }

                    section_num.html(json.section_num);
                    problem_set.html(json.problem_set);

                    // Not show date if summary
                    if (name == "Summary") {

                        start_time.html(" ");
                        due_time.html(" ");

                        $("#as-due-time-div").hide();
                        $("#as-start-time-div").hide();

                    } else {

                        $("#as-due-time-div").show();
                        $("#as-start-time-div").show();

                        start_time.html(moment(parseInt(json.start_time)).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"));
                        due_time.html(moment(parseInt(json.due_time)).format("MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"));
                    }

                    student_am.html(json.student_am);
                    student_total.html(json.student_total);
                    submit_am.html(json.submit_am);
                    submit_total.html(json.submit_total);
                    avg_score.html(json.avg_score);

                    danger.html(json.danger);
                    warning.html(json.warning);
                    success.html(json.success);

                    danger_list.html(json.danger_list);
                    warning_list.html(json.warning_list);
                    success_list.html(json.success_list);

                }

                // Load the Visualization API and the piechart package.
                google.load("visualization", "1", {
                    packages: ["corechart"]
                });
                google.setOnLoadCallback(drawChart());

                function drawChart() {

                    var options = {
                        width: 160,
                        height: 160,
                        chartArea: {
                            left: 10,
                            top: 20,
                            width: "100%",
                            height: "100%"
                        },


                        colors: ['#F46E4E', '#F9C262', '#ADB55E', ],
                        legend: 'none',
                        enableInteractivity: false,
                        pieSliceText: 'none',

                    };

                    var chart = new google.visualization.PieChart(document.getElementById('piechart'));
                    var data = {};

                    $.each(objects.assignments, function(i, v) {
                     console.log(v);

                        var header = v.header;
                        var name  = v.name;
                        var total = header.danger + header.warning + header.success;

                        data[i] = new google.visualization.arrayToDataTable([

                            ['Piechart', 'Number of Skills'],
                            ['danger', (header.danger / total) * 100],
                            ['warning', (header.warning / total) * 100],
                            ['success', (header.success / total) * 100],

                            ]);

                        // Auto Populate the dropdown-menu
                        if (i == 0) {
                            $("#as-dd.dropdown").append('<option value="' + name + '"> Summary </option>');
                        } else {
                            $("#as-dd.dropdown").append('<option value="' + name + '">' + name + '</option>');
                        }

                    });

                    // Dropdown-menu change
                    $('#as-dd').on('change', function() {
                        var value = $(this).val();
                        updateInfo(value);
                        chart.draw(data[value], options);
                    });

                    // Initializing
                    updateInfo("0");
                    chart.draw(data[0], options);

                }

            }

        });

});

});
```

Comment: When you ask if you should do all logic **within** Ajax success, it may mean two different things. First, physically speaking: IMO you might consider to locate your `updateInfo()` and `drawChart()` functions outside of the Ajax `success:`, for readalility. This way, the main body of the success process appears more clearly. Then, logically speaking: I didn' take time to precisely understand how this works, but I guess you should have some code (may be the `Initializing` sequence?) outside of the `success:` part, something like a `always:`part, to cover the case of potential errors.

Answer (score 1):

I'm agree with the improvements suggested by @cfreed, you should extract `updateInfo()` and `drawChart()` outside of the ajax call. This should be a better split btw the data/view. A side effect, could be doesn't have all jquery selectors on the top of the request.

Also, I would like add my owns:

- If you are using `$.ajax` with that configuration, you can cosidere use the [shortwhand](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) mehtods like `$.post`
- is a good convention use camelCase instead of sanake_case for
  variable names.
- you should consider use some kind of default value for the assigments:

  `var json = objects.assignments[x].header || {}`
  not always the server response with the full data. Asume null values and considere to use [null object pattern](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Null_Object_pattern).
- Be more expresive in name variables:

  `$.each(objects.assignments, function(i, v) {//who is v?`